# What are the advantages of tensor network algorithms over monte-carlo simulations in terms of time-evolution?

Tags: computational-physics, simulations, algorithms, tensor-network

I understand that tensor networks and monte carlo simulations are based on completely different principles. However, to my knowledge both are used to simulate the time evolution of a system. Is there any advantage to using one method over the other?

Edit: Sorry if this wasn't clear but my question is purely in relation to the time evolution of quantum systems. Specifically, do both methods achieve the same result at the end of the simulation, is one method more accurate than the other, and so on?

Comment: I'm afraid that you're a bit off-topic here

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Add some details of the problem you're dealing with, at least

Comment: This is a comparison of computer related processes and not a question about physics, that's why it's off topic.

Comment: @Triatticus What do you mean? This is a comparison of two different methods to simulate physical problems, which perform differently because they capture their physics in a specific way. It is as much about physics as any question about numerical methods for the simulation of physical problems, which is certainly on-topic here. (There's even a tag!)

Comment: @Souroy Is your question specifically about simulating time evolution? Then you should make this more clear, also e.g. in the title.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch sure but this isn't even being asked with the context of physics but the comparison of two algorithms, this is first and foremost a site for questions about physics. But this question would likely get a better response from a more computer centric field. Just because a tag exists doesn't mean this is the best place for it and I find the question isn't phrased in a way to make it applicable here.

Comment: @Souroy Your question has some issues: First, title and question body ask different things. Second, it might help to focus the question more. Third, some background might help. I, e.g., have no idea whatsoever how time evolution is simulated with Monte Carlo.

Comment: @Triatticus From the context of the question it is clear it is about time evolution of quantum many-body systems -- very much physics. (I agree the question has shortcomings, so this is only clear to people who know the context, but this means it has to be edited, not migrated.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Sure but this is still not physically focused enough, that's just asking generally about solving some complex system...with still a hard focus on the algorithms themselves. If the question wants to be focused more to physics an actually physical problems has to be presented. What kind of quantum many body problem, what's the potential, what are the interactions..etc. Plus these edits were just made.

Comment: @Triatticus I'm not saying the question is great as it is. But for sure, it was always a question about very physics-specific algorithms, which makes it on topic here. (OTOH, Comp. Sciences does not seem to be at all a good place for these types of questions.) There is many aspects of the physics of systems going into the difficulty of simulating time evolutoins, which require a physics perspective to understand them. And understanding a general algorithm to simulate quantum spin systems is certainly more important then understanding its application to a specific problem. ...

Comment: I would argue the converse: If it is too focused, its more akin to homework-type problems, whereas asking about certain algorithms tailored to certain complex quantum systems is much more in the spirit of this site. (This is not to argue in favor of the current question, but the *topic* of the  question is definitely on-topic here.

Comment: This is 100% a physics question, and as a CMT person, I not only understood this question from the title alone, but am quite curious if any experts have an answer. I know that in 1d for static properties, DMRG is pretty much always better than QMC for a given amount of memory. But for time evolution, I'm less sure in part because tDMRG can't get to super late times and also because I'm less familiar with MC time evolution of many-body quantum systems. My guess is MC could be better since entanglement basically always grows under evolution?

Comment: These people just don't know, so they instead argue if an entire branch of physics is physics. Sorry for the state of this site.